# PHP Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php, shell

i try to run a command in server from php
so i added this code in a php file

```
 shell_exec($cmd);  

 echo $cmd = "at ".$_POST['time1']." <<< '/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl  ".$_POST['url']." -o ".$out." && /root/bin/ffmpeg -y -i ".$out." -c:v libx264 -s 640x360 -b:v 300k -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -c:a aac FILMA/".$out."___www.example.com___.mp4 && rm -f ".$out."'";
```

When i run it i get this error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cmd in /var/www/html/1.php on line __, referer: http://example.com/1.php

Comment: its not duplicate, this is different problem

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but I believe the cmd variable is undefined... @Gloytoshtyqo No, it is the exact same problem. You are obviously not making any effort to read and understand anything.

Comment: It is the same problem. `$cmd` is not defined. Here `shell_exec($cmd);`  The `$cmd` is not previously defined. If that is not the case you went to minimal, and the error message should be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting to use `$cmd` before you have defined it. You use it on line 1 and define it on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

You must run:

```
shell_exec($cmd);
```

after defining $cmd.

Example:

```
$cmd = "at ".$_POST['time1']." <<< '/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl  ".$_POST['url']." -o ".$out." && /root/bin/ffmpeg -y -i ".$out." -c:v libx264 -s 640x360 -b:v 300k -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -c:a aac FILMA/".$out."___www.example.com___.mp4 && rm -f ".$out."'";

shell_exec($cmd);
```